# Is the joint distribution of any two uncorrelated normally distributed random variables bivariate normal?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, density-function, bivariate-distributions

Originally I was only going to ask if the joint distribution of any two normally distributed is random variables bivariate normal, however it seems that a large set of counterexamples can be found [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/). Is there any set of criterion for which two normally distributed random variables need to satisfy in order to have a bivariate normal joint distribution?

Comment: For _normal_ variables on the same space, does uncorrelated imply independent?